# Inserting an array of arrays as the last column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

and an array B:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

I want to make array B as the last column of array A, so I want the result array (let's call it C) to look like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, [1, 0]],
       [1, 1, 1, [1, 0]],
       [2, 2, 2, [0, 1]]])
```

I tried: `np.insert(a,-1,b,axis=1)` , but this gave me an error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (3,3)
```

Comment: What's with those inserted brackets there?

Comment: what inserted brackets?

Comment: @EricChen Are you actually trying to insert it as a column (why?), or as two columns?

Comment: In the first row you have : `..1, 2, 3, [1,`. that bracket. I don't think that NumPy arrays could have those.

Comment: oh thanks, I think that's the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 1, 1], 
              [2, 2, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
np.hstack([a,b])
```

Which results in:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print zip(*zip(*a)+[b.tolist(),])
```

although it wont be a numpy array afterwards

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
>>> b
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
>>> zip(*zip(*a)+[b.tolist(),])
[(1, 2, 3, [1, 0]), (1, 1, 1, [1, 0]), (2, 2, 2, [0, 1])]
```